# Insert second domain rules htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I bought a second domain and added it to my hosting, how do I configure the htaccess file to redirect the pages of the second domain to its own folder?
this is my file currently, the first domain is inside the public folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^sitemap/sitemap-surveys.xml$   sitemap/sitemap-surveys.php
RewriteRule ^sitemap/sitemap-users.xml$   sitemap/sitemap-users.php
RewriteRule ^sitemap/sitemap-flashpinions.xml$   sitemap/sitemap-flashpinions.php
RedirectMatch ^/$ /accounts/index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/about/index.html$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

The second domain is located inside the site2 folder

Comment: Thank you for sharing your rules in your question. Could you please do mention sample/examples of links also from which url to which url you want to redirect/rewrite? That will give us better understand of your question, thank you.

Comment: Currently the following code redirects all the pages of sito1.com to public/public/index.php and I manage everything through routing. I would like the pages of site2 to be redirected to site2/public/index.php Thanks

Comment: So it means all the rules you want to redirect to new sub-domain? Or only index.php rules?

Comment: site2.com is not a subdomain of site1.com. They are two independent domains, hosted on the same host

Comment: Hi, I was late last night too and after two hours I glued your rules and as if by magic they worked. Both domains are working fine, just the start page of both domains is not working. Site1.com and site2.com give 404 errors while all other pages are correctly displayed. I think it's an easy rule to fix, can you still help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Considering that any url which is having your new domain should be rewritten by site2/public/index.php file, make sure your htaccess should be in same folder where htaccess, site2 folder and site1 folders are present.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(site2)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^ %1/public/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap/sitemap-surveys.xml$   sitemap/sitemap-surveys.php
RewriteRule ^sitemap/sitemap-users.xml$   sitemap/sitemap-users.php
RewriteRule ^sitemap/sitemap-flashpinions.xml$   sitemap/sitemap-flashpinions.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(site2)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /accounts/index [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/about/index.html$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

How I did testing for above is(I am using localhost here you can use your domain name here), how my folder locations look like.

```
/var/www/html/.htaccess
/var/www/html/site2/
/var/www/html/site2/public/index.php
```

Testing results:

```
curl -IL "http://localhost:80/test/blabla"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Comment: I solved it with RedirectMatch ^/$ /accounts/index and I manage everything through rounting. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @Gae, your welcome cheers :) can you please edit my post add it a separate section saying OP's edit: and add your rules happy learning